# how do I use animateMotion on only a part of a path?

Tags: animation, svg

I have a path that I want to animate an element (image in this case) along. But I just want it to animate along a part of the path. Wait there until the user interacts and then animate it along the rest of the path.

With other animations you could always specify `from` and `to` attributes. My thought was that you could do it like this:

JavaScript

```
//user press some key
animationElement.setAttribute("from", "0.0"); //beginning of path
animationElement.setAttribute("to", "0.5"); //middle of path
animationElement.beginElement();
...
//user presses another key
animationElement.setAttribute("from", "0.5"); //middle of path
animationElement.setAttribute("to", "1.0"); //end of path
animationElement.beginElement();
```

svg

```
<path id="myPath" d="m1119,29l-80,137l-601,52l-152,318l-381,218" stroke="#000000" fill="none" pathLength="1" />
<image xlink:href="someImage.png" width="231" height="262">
  <animateMotion fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" end="indefinite" from="0" to="0.4">
    <mpath xlink:href="#myPath" />
  </animateMotion>
</image>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered splitting the motionpath in two parts, and then changing the xlink:href on the mpath element?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to do the same thing without success.

I would not expect the from/to described in your question to work because these attributes are not appropriate.

I have been experimenting with keyTimes and keyPoints but these do not seem to work properly (when viewed in chrome or Firefox). Any inconsistent settings break the animation and any consistent settings just have the motion moving at a constant rate across the whole path whatever they are set to.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the svg implementation or not. For example:
keyTimes="0;0.2;0.3;0.9;1" keyPoints="0;0.5;0.6;0.7;1" produces smooth movement across the path.
If they worked I think that keyTimes="0;1" keyPoints="0;0.5" would achieve the desired objective.

Currently I'm having to use multiple paths and thread the animations together appropriately which is complex and annoying but at least it gets the job done.